# Запретить изменение select. disabled не подходит

Tags: php, html

Есть форма, там тег select, вот как запретить его редактирование не используя disabled. Потому что этот disabled обходится очень просто.

Comment: да все обходится. просто игнорируйте его значение, когда форма приходит на сервер

Comment: Дело в том, что данные формы это так сказать элементы браузера (DOM), а у в любом современном браузере есть редактор этих элементов, и вы никак не защититесь от этого на стороне клиента, он может редактировать добавлять и удалять их, единственное что вы можете, это не пересылать данные селекта либо игнорировать его на стороне сервера как написал вам **splash58**

Comment: Вот если бы вы прикрепили html где этот селект, потом к примеру js который отсылает данные, кусок серверной обработке (необязательно) было бы наглядней и люди бы подсказали как стоит лучше действовать.

Comment: Если данные формы из селекта нельзя редактировать - то зачем вообще выводить селект?

Comment: Можно брать значение до редактирования и его же вставлять после "редактирования" (change event). Но смысла в этом чуть меньше чем нет, как и написал [u-mulder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178087/u-mulder)